# YANG Input based on another input

Tags: yang

I have to take an input in rpc only in one previous input is taken. For Example if we input value for field a then value for field b is compulsory.

I am new to it, I tried giving mandatory true for the last value.

Answer (score 1):

To have a second parameter become conditionally mandatory based on the first parameter, use `when` and `mandatory` at the same time.

```
module a {
    yang-version 1.1;
    namespace "a:uri";
    prefix "a"; 

    rpc foo {
        input {
            leaf first {
                type uint8;
            }
            leaf second {
                when "../first"; // <--
                type uint8;
                mandatory true;  // <--
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `when "../first";` condition, which is defined for `leaf second` says something like: "in a valid rpc instance document, leaf 'second' may only appear if leaf 'first' exists". If you add the `mandatory true` to `leaf second`, this becomes: "in a valid rpc instance document, leaf 'second' must appear if leaf 'first' exists."

Note that `leaf first` is optional in my example. `rpc foo` may only be sent without parameters or with both parameters at the same time.

Why does it work that way?

[RFC 7950, Section 7.14.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-7.14.2) describes how `input` definitions work:

> The "input" statement, which is optional, is used to define input
> parameters to the operation.  It does not take an argument.  The
> substatements to "input" define nodes under the operation's input
> node.
>
> **If a leaf in the input tree has a "mandatory" statement with the
> value "true", the leaf MUST be present in an RPC invocation.**
>
> If a leaf in the input tree has a default value, the server MUST use
> this value in the same cases as those described in Section 7.6.1.  In
> these cases, the server MUST operationally behave as if the leaf was
> present in the RPC invocation with the default value as its value.
>
> If a leaf-list in the input tree has one or more default values, the
> server MUST use these values in the same cases as those described in
> Section 7.7.2.  In these cases, the server MUST operationally behave
> as if the leaf-list was present in the RPC invocation with the
> default values as its values.
>
> Since the input tree is not part of any datastore, all "config"
> statements for nodes in the input tree are ignored.
>
> **If any node has a "when" statement that would evaluate to "false",
> then this node MUST NOT be present in the input tree.**

[Section 8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-8.1) of the same RFC describes how constraints such as `when` and `mandatory` are applied - the `when` condition takes precedence:

> **o  The "mandatory" constraint is enforced for leafs and choices,
> unless the node or any of its ancestors has a "when" condition or
> "if-feature" expression that evaluates to "false".**